# plotting contours on grid of scatterplots with pairs() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've had some success making a grid of scatter plots showing every combination of columns in a data frame using pairs() in R.  I followed [this guide](http://gastonsanchez.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/scatterplot-matrices-with-ggplot/) and got the scatter plot matrix working well.  Now I want to plot contours of an additional variable on these scatter plots.

Example:

```
data = iris # use the iris data
head( data )
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

let's say I want to make a scatter plot matrix with all combinations of Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, and Petal.Length.  I can do that easily with pairs

```
pairs( data[ ,1:3 ] )
```

but I also want to plot contours of Petal.Width on each of these frames.

I've tried

```
pairs( data[ ,1:3 ] ) + stat_contours()
```

but I get

```
Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm assuming that's because pairs() is no longer a ggplot object.  Is there a way around this?  I'm new to R and ggplot, but I'm pretty sure that last line I typed is nonsense.

Comment: If you insert `stat_density2d()` into the 'pairs plot' ggplot code right at the bottom of the blog post you link to, then you'll get contours in the pairs plot.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. pairs() is a function from the "traditional" graphics system, whereas ggplot is based on grid. I think combining the two of them is not possible, at least in a convenient way. Try this (plotmatrix is the ggplot equivalent of pairs())

`plotmatrix(iris[,1:3]) + stat_density2d()`

However, the plotmatrix function is deprecated (it is still working on my system - and it is the easiest solution I have in mind... So it is worth to give it a try)